# Integral closure of $A \subseteq B$ is a subring of $B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-extensions

So I have the following exercise:

**Let $A \subseteq B$ both rings, prove that $\hat{A} = \left\{\alpha \in B: f(\alpha) = 0 \right\}$ is a subring of  $B$, with $f(x) \in A[x]$ some monic polynomial.**

And I have to prove it with the clasic subring test (substraction and multiplication closure in $\hat{A}$) and I already got the multiplication closure but still stuck with the substraction closure:

$$f(\alpha - \beta) = (\alpha - \beta)^n + a_{n-1}(\alpha - \beta)^{n-1} + \dots + a_1(\alpha - \beta) + a_0, \ \alpha, \beta \in \hat{A}$$

I thought about using binomial newton but I was wondering if there was another easier way to do it.

Comment: Well, you could do this: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integral_Closure_is_Subring and maybe adapt it to your setting

Comment: @MichaelMorrow I've seen that proof but in this case nor $A$ or $B$ are conmutative hence I can't use the integral extension (to my knowledge, if I'm wrong please correct me) so, how could I adapt that proof to this scenario?